# How to read logical data from a file in R

Tags: r

I generated a file which contains a logical value either a "TRUE" or a "FALSE" on each line. Now I would like to read the logical data from the file into R. However the data that are read in are of mode "character" not logical values. I was wondering how to read the data as logical values from the file.

My R code is

```
cat(FALSE,"\n", file="1.txt", append=FALSE);
for (i in 2:5) cat(TRUE,"\n",file="1.txt", append=TRUE);
a=scan(file="1.txt", what="logical")
```

The output is:

```
> mode(a)
[1] "character"
> mode(a[1])
[1] "character"
> a[1]
[1] "FALSE"
```

I want a[1] to be logical value.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, now I get it. You have to read `?scan` very carefully to see that what you've done is not what `scan()` wants for the `what` argument. I missed this first time and then wondered why your code wasn't working. This is the key section:

```
what: the type of ‘what’ gives the type of data to be read.  The
      supported types are ‘logical’, ‘integer’, ‘numeric’,
      ‘complex’, ‘character’, ‘raw’ and ‘list’.
```

and the key phrase is **type**. So you need to pass an object of the correct **type** to argument `what`.

In your example:

```
> typeof("logical")
[1] "character"
```

So `scan()` reads in an object of type `"character"`.

The solution is simply to use `what = TRUE`, or indeed anything that R considers a logical (see comments to this answer), instead

```
> typeof(TRUE)
[1] "logical"
> ## or
> typeof(logical())
[1] "logical"

## So now read in with what = TRUE
> a <- scan(file="1.txt", what = TRUE)
Read 5 items
> class(a)
[1] "logical"
> typeof(a)
[1] "logical"
```

`read.table()` is more logical in how you tell it what the data to be read in are. The equivalent call there would be:

```
> b <- read.table("1.txt", colClasses = "logical")[,]
> class(b)
[1] "logical"
> typeof(b)
[1] "logical"
```

HTH

Comment: As `what` one could use `NA` cause `typeof(NA)` is `logical`. And for other types special `NA`'s could be used: `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_character_`, `NA_complex_`.

Comment: Or good old `logical(0)`... I think this is the most logical one to use.

Comment: @mbq Your way is better way :)

Comment: @mbq: thanks for that suggestion. I've edited my answer to include mention of this as `logical()` (saves typing one character ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use  `a=='TRUE'->a`.

Comment: This works well when dealing with nonstandard types of logical data; say `'Yes'/'No'`, `7/-5` or just `'true'/'false'`.