# How to read logical data from a file in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read logical data from a file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784617/how-to-read-logical-data-from-a-file-in-r)

I generated a file which contains a logical value either a "TRUE" or a "FALSE" on each line. Now I would like to read the logical data from the file into R. However the data that are read in are of mode "character" not logical values. I was wondering how to read the data as logical values from the file.

My R code is

```
cat(FALSE,"\n", file="1.txt", append=FALSE);
for (i in 2:5) cat(TRUE,"\n",file="1.txt", append=TRUE);
a=scan(file="1.txt", what="logical")
```

The output is:

```
> mode(a)
1] "character"
> mode(a[1])
[1] "character"
> a[1]
[1] "FALSE"
```

I want a[1] to be logical value.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
a=scan(file="1.txt", what="logical")
```

try:

```
a = scan(file="1.txt", what=logical(0))
```

See `?scan` for documentation.

Comment: THanks! That works! I tried to read the help documentation, but still not sure what is the difference between what="logical" and what=logical(0)? Thanks!

Comment: Basically, it wants an object of the actual type to which values should be coerced.  You could also just say `scan(file='1.txt', what=TRUE)` and it would work the same.  `logical(0)` is a cleaner way, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

```
a
[1] "FALSE" "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE" 
a <- as.logical(a)
a
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```